# bash: How to modify a string within a field

Tags: bash, awk, cut

I have the following lines:

```
field1    1-23_4_5    field3
field1    2-40_5_7    field3
field1    3-43_7_9    field3
             .
             .
             .
```

I would like to modify the second field so that

`1-23_4_5` becomes `1-23`

I am thinking the combination of `awk` and `cut` would do the trick. Is there a simple way to go about this?

Thank you so much for your help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Through awk,

```
$ awk 'sub(/_[^_]*_[^_]*$/,"",$2)1' file
field1 1-23 field3
field1 2-40 field3
field1 3-43 field3
```

Through sed,

```
$ sed 's/^\([^ ]\+\ *[^_]\+\)[^ ]\+/\1/g' file
field1    1-23    field3
field1    2-40    field3
field1    3-43    field3
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one `awk` version:

```
awk '{split($2,a,"_");$2=a[1]}1' file
field1 1-23 field3
field1 2-40 field3
field1 3-43 field3
```

Divide field `2` by `_` and use only first part.
PS it changes the formatting. (normal with awk)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this quite easily with a simple bash script using `read` and `substring extraction`:

```
#!/bin/bash

## validate input file
[ -r "$1" ] || { printf "Error: insufficient input. Usage %s <filename>\n"; exit 1; }

## read and extract substring of field2
while read -r f1 f2 f3 || [ -n "$f3" ]; do 
    printf "%s    %s    %s\n" "$f1" "${f2%%_*}" "$f3"; 
done < "$1"
```

**test file:**

```
$ cat dat/field.txt
field1    1-23_4_5    field3
field1    2-40_5_7    field3
field1    3-43_7_9    field3
```

**output:**

```
$ bash fields.sh dat/field.txt
field1    1-23    field3
field1    2-40    field3
field1    3-43    field3
```